# How do I generate an absolute OData URL for a given entity type?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, odata

I have a working OData implementation with routes setup in the typical way:

```
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<Person>("People");

configuration.Routes.MapODataRoute(routeName:"OData", routePrefix:"odata", model:builder.GetEdmModel());
```

I'm looking for a way to programatically generate an absolute URL for a registered entity set **from outside of any OData action**.  For example, I want to request the OData endpoint for the `Person` type and get back `"http://host/odata/People"`.

The standard URL helpers don't seem to apply since the OData routing is convention-based.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to request the OData endpoint for the Person type and get back 'http://host/odata/People'"? What is the request?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to leverage the IEdmModel instance generated by the ODataConventionModelBuilder.GetEdmModel().

```
IEdmModel model = builder.GetEdmModel(); // the builder is what you defined in the question.
var entitySetName = "";
foreach (var temp in model.FindEntityContainer("Container").EntitySets())
{
    if (temp.ElementType.Name == "Person")
    {
        entitySetName = temp.Name;
        break;
    }
}
return "http://host/odata/"+entitySetName;
```

Note: if you define more than one entity set for an entity type, the upper code only returns the first one.

Comment: In general, it's recommended to use `String.Concat()` or `String.Format()` for building strings, rather than `+`; the performance is significantly better for a start. In this scenario, the impact will be minimal, admittedly, but it's best to stick to the habit.