# Get entitySetName from IEdmModel

Tags: c#, odata

I'm building an extended OData client based on `DataServiceContext`. I have a working `IEdmModel`, and can bind the entities to it. But I want to fetch the entitySetName based on the `Type`.

For instance, if you want to get all the products from [Odata.org example](http://services.odata.org/V4/OData/OData.svc), the entitySetName is **Products**. Can I somehow get this from `IEdmModel` if I only know that the type is `Product`? Or if I know that the model type is `Category`, the entitySetName is **Categories**.

I know that I can try to manually pluralize it (by appending *s* to the type and so on), but I figure there must be a more correct way to do it?

The reason why I want this is that I'm using `DataServiceContext.CreateQuery<T>`, which require the entitySetName as string.

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a data service query for data of a specified generic type.
/// </summary>
/// 
/// <returns>
/// A new <see cref="T:Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQuery`1"/> instance that represents a data service query.
/// </returns>
/// <param name="entitySetName">A string that resolves to a URI.</param><typeparam name="T">The type returned by the query</typeparam>
/// <remarks>
/// create a query based on (BaseUri + relativeUri)
/// </remarks>
public DataServiceQuery<T> CreateQuery<T>(string entitySetName)
{

}
```

I have seen this question, but it's a slightly different scope.

[How do I generate an absolute OData URL for a given entity type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255143/how-do-i-generate-an-absolute-odata-url-for-a-given-entity-type)

`IEdmModel.EntityContainer.Elements` returns an `IEnumerable<IEdmEntityContainerElement>`, which in fact is a `IEnumerable<CsdlSemanticsEntitySet>`. It contains the entitySetName but due to it's protection level I cannot cast to it and therefore I cannot get it.

Comment: Maybe you can use reflection to get the Name of the entitySet

Comment: @scher - Yes, but it seems like a workaround..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you want this:

```
model.EntityContainer.Elements.OfType<IEdmEntitySet>()....
```